# TTThumbView + NavigationBar

Tags: iphone, objective-c, three20

I use an application with an UINavigationBar, in a part of my application I click on a button to use the the TTThumbViewController (MockPhotoSource), the problem is when I click back on the NavigationBar it seems to add the property of three20 navigationBar to my original NavigationBar. 
How can I disable the three20 NavigationBar when I click Back?

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This sounds like you're not using the TTNavigator and URL Mapping for navigation. So you'll likely need to add:

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleDefault;
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleDefault animated:YES];
```

To your viewWillAppear: method for the previous view.

Comment: I have another question with that. In my app I set the statut Bar to NO, so I can navigate without it but everytime I go to the TTPhotoView it will reappear and stay in all the navigation.